# OSM Public_Transport Tiles won't work from Mobile Atlas Creator when put into Android Studio

Tags: android, offline, osmdroid

It won't view. I tried following all of the instructions i found online like in stackoverflow or in github but it still won't work. It does not view the tiles i have. I have an OSMPublicTransport Map created in MOBAC. I renamed it into PUBLIC_TRANSPORT.zip then put it on my LG mobile phone on my sdcard/osmdroid/. I tried running it but it does not view the tile, just the grid. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.android.paths;


import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.ITileSource;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static File OSMDROID_PATH = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "osmdroid");
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("PUBLIC_TRANSPORT", 14, 16, 256, ".png", new String[] {
                "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/"}));
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        map.setUseDataConnection(false); //optional, but a good way to prevent loading from the network and test your zip loading.
        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(14);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(121.026764, 14.566305);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
    }

}
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Comments do not bump. Edits to the question do, but also don't edit just to add "bump"

Comment: @cricket_007 alright, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Open the zip file, there should be a single folder in it. That's the tile source name.  I bet it doesn't match what it is set on the source instance

Either rename the folder in the zip or update you code to match the source name

Comment: the source inside the .zip file is also called PUBLIC_TRANSPORT but it still won't work.